# How to get Button to Update Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a View where in a GridView is generated of checklist to do items. One particular item is status. If the item isn't done, a button is shown to mark the item as done as well as mark who clicked the button and when:

```
    <td>
        @if (item.status.Equals("Done"))
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
        }
        else
        {
            <input type="button" title="TestTitle" value="TestValue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Update", "Checklist", new { item = item})'" />
        }
    </td>
```

I took the code from the scaffolded Edit and modified it slightly in my ChecklistController as all I want to do is modify three columns in the DB:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update([Bind(Include = "ID,ww,taskitem,owner,manager,project,status,applied_by,timestamp")] TaskItem taskItem)
{
    taskItem.timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    taskItem.applied_by = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    taskItem.status = "Done";

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(taskItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View("Index", db.TaskItemSet.ToList());
}
```

I'm somewhat new to binding and anon types so regardless of using `new { item = item}`, `new { id = item.id}` or `new {item}` I get:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Checklist/Update
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0

What am I doing wrong and how do I get to do what I want?

Comment: `location.href` makes a GET call. You need to create a form for each item (and it should post back just the ID of the object, not the complete model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i think you should post it as an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick="location.href='...'"` is making a GET call to a method which does not exist (you only have a POST method).

Change you view to to include a form for each item with the appropriate status

```
else
{
  using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Checklist", new { id = item.ID }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" title="TestTitle" value="TestValue" />
  }
}
```

And modify the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(int ID)
{
  // Get the model
  TaskItem model = db.TaskItems.Where(m => m.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
  // Update properties
  model.timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
  model.applied_by = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
  model.status = "Done";
  // Save and redirect
  db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Side note: If the view that these buttons are on is the `Index` view, then you would get far better performance by using ajax to post the value and then just updating the DOM to replace the button with the status text

Comment: The @ before using needs to be removed otherwise it works nicely. Thanks for the explanation; I'll look into ajax after I've gotten the core features working as a proof of concept, but yes from a user standpoint it would be much nicer to have the DOM replace the button with text rather than basically causing the page to refresh.